# Uncaught TypeError: proxy set handler returned false for property '"length"'

Tags: javascript, oop, es6-proxy

I started testing the following proxy pattern, and got the titled error when using the `.splice()` method.

```js
class A extends Array {
  constructor(...x) {
    super(...x)
    return new Proxy(this, {
      set(o,p,v) {
        console.log("set: ",o,p,v)
        return o[p] = v
      },
            
      get(o,p) {
        console.log("get: ",o,p)
        return o[p]
      },
    })
  }
}

const a = new A(1,2,3)

a.splice(1,0,"a")
```

Producing the following console output:

```
get:  Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ] splice
get:  Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ] length
get:  Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ] constructor
set:  Array [] length 0

Uncaught TypeError: proxy set handler returned false for property '"length"'
    InnerModuleEvaluation self-hosted:2411
    InnerModuleEvaluation self-hosted:2411
    evaluation self-hosted:2358
```

Does anyone know what internal specifics I am missing that requires `set` to return `true` in the case of using `.splice()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not just the `splice` method, this happens in all [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) code when attempting to set a non-writable property. The falsy return value of the trap handler indicates that setting the property failed.

```js
"use strict";
const a = new Proxy([1,2,3], {
  set(o,p,v) {
    console.log("set: ",o,p,v)
    return o[p] = v
  },
});
a.length = 0; // TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'length'
```

In your case, the problem is that you return the new property value, while [a `set` trap ought to return a boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set#return_value). So it "works" when you set the `a.length = 5`, but not for `a.length = 0`. Fix this by using the default implementation provided by the [`Reflect` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) for the trap, if all you want is to log and not actually intercept the assignment, and do not forget the *receiver* parameter:

```
const handler = {
  set(o,p,v,r) {
    console.log("set: ",o,p,v)
    return Reflect.set(o,p,v,r);
  },
  get(o,p,r) {
    console.log("get: ",o,p)
    return Reflect.get(o,p,r);
  },
}

class A extends Array {
  constructor(...x) {
    super(...x)
    return new Proxy(this, handler)
  }
}
```

Comment: Your link to docs was a lifesaver thanks :)

Comment: Always read the docs first before using advanced features like proxies :-)